# How can I run from crontab a python script that needs python 3 when the installed python is version 2

Tags: python, linux

I have a Linux machine that runs Python 2.6 and I have a python script A that uses some modules that need Python 3. If I want to run this script I use this command: 
    scl enable rh-python36 bash
 and it switches to Python 3.6

Now I need to put in crontab this script and run it hourly but it doesn`t run because the version is 2.6

I wrote another script:

```
import os

os.system("scl enable rh-python36 bash")
os.system("python script.py")
```

If I manually run this script it only switches to python 3 but it doesnt run the second os.system command... another thing I tried is putting in crontab both commands with && between them but it doesn`t work also...

So how can I run from crontab a python script that needs python 3 when the installed python is version 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can run both commands in one session using the `&&` operator. You also need to call the right version of Python (either python3 or python36)

```
import os

os.system("scl enable rh-python36 bash && python3 script.py")
```